# How to clear Ext JS store without affecting/deleting records in the server

Tags: extjs

I have a Ext JS grid store with `autosave` set to `false`.

I want to clear ONLY the local store, without affecting/deleting records in the server.

If I try `store.removeAll()`, then when the next store write occurs, all records are deleted.

How to call `store.removeAll` with clearing all pending changes after it?

Comment: can you provide your store and proxy code?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
Store.loadData([],false);
```

This statement drop local cache and not send changes to server side

Comment: thats really great.. I was unware about this and was using `removeAll()`

Answer (score 6):

The removeAll has a silent parameter that can be used to clear records rather than delete from the server:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-removeAll

```
gridPanel.store.removeAll(true);
```

From the code comments:

```
    if (silent !== true) {  // <-- prevents write-actions when we just want to clear a store.
        this.fireEvent('clear', this, items);
    }
```

If you then manually want to update a GridPanel to clear all rows you need to call:

```
gridPanel.view.refresh();
```

Answer (score 2):

For ExtJS 4.1, this will clear buffer cache (prefetched data), so the next time you load (or loadPage), store will reload the pages from scratch:

```
store.pageMap.clear();
```

which was previously done as:

```
store.prefetchData.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from what I understand you want to ignore changes to the local store and not send it to the server side. Have you tried using:

```
myStore.rejectChanges();
```

This method clears all outstanding changes on all modified records. This will reject all pending changes.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.